# Codeigniter $route

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I have a doubt. In my route, I have something like this:

```
$route['events(:any)'] = "events/view/$0";
```

But I need to except one word, in my case 'gallery'.

So, any url with events excepts gallery will route
to `events/view/$0` and gallery will route to `events/gallery`

But `$route['events(:any)']` can be `events-social`, or `events-corp`, or `events-indor`

How do I do that? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since routes are run in the order they are defined, you can simply define a `gallery` route first:

```
$route['events-gallery'] = "events/gallery";
$route['events-(:any)'] = "events/view/$0";
```

Note the added hyphen in `events-(:any)` in the second route above. Based on the description of what you're trying to achieve, I think you're missing that from your code.